# How do I capture a matrix from a user input and print it out as the user input it?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm messing around with numpy trying to create a 3x3 matrix. I want to capture the matrix input via user input and then print the matrix out as the user entered it.

Here's what I have now, it throws a

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

when I run it and I have no idea why. I'm not entering the letter "a" anywhere, only numbers.

```py
def matrix():
    row = int(3)
    column = int(3)
    matrix_input = []
    print("Enter the entries in a single line (separated by space): ")
    for i in range(row):  # A for loop for row entries
        entries = []
        for j in range(column):  # A for loop for column entries
            entries.append(int(input()))
        matrix_input.append(entries)

    # matrix_input = np.array(entries).reshape(row, column)
    print(matrix_input)
```

The goal is to get the user to input 3 numbers on three separate lines.
Example:

```
130
304
603
```

The program would then type this back out exactly as the user entered it and in the same format.

```
130
304
603
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To debug something like this note the line that causes the error.  I assume it's `entries.append(int(input()))` (but only you know for sure).  Then start splitting it up, and if needed print some intermediate steps.  Better yet try this code in an interactive session where you can examine the results one after the other.

Comment: Is that the full error message?

Comment: I ran the code and you got the line that causes the error right. The full exception was `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` So he probably just needs an exit condition?

Comment: If you want input just like the user entered it, why go though all that list of list of `int` business?  Just collect the input strings, and print them back one at a time.  Focus on what kind of data structure you create, not on the print display!

Answer (score 3):

Right now, your code asks for each element seperately. If you enter numbers until it ends itself like

```
111
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
```

the program will return

```
[[111, 222, 333], [444, 555, 666], [777, 888, 999]]
```

This happens because the `input()` is inside the inner most loop, and is consequently called 9 times.

So if you want to enter the values separated by space as indicated, you could use list comprehension to convert this to a list of numbers:

```
row = int(3)
matrix_input = []
print("Enter the entries in a single line (separated by space): ")
for i in range(row):  # A for loop for row entries
    matrix_input.append([int(k) for k in input().split(' ')])

for out in matrix_input:
    print('{0} {1} {2}'.format(*out))
```

This will ask for three entries, which are split along the spaces and converted to integer. If you want floats, you could use `float(k)` instead of `int(k)`.
The print command uses unpacking and the fact that the `for ... in` returns the rows.

Alternatively, you could use `' '.join()`, which is more flexible:

```
for out in matrix_input:
    print(' '.join([str(el) for el in out]))
```

This is in fact the inverse operation of the construction of the matrix.

Comment: This works great but how would print the output to look the same as when the user entered it?

Comment: See my edit: the for loop loops over the rows, and the formatted output takes the  elements of the row and prints them. Note however, that this solution is quite static. I.e. if you want 4 elements or only 2 in a row, this does not work anymore and has to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

```
def matrix(): 
    row = int(3)
    column = int(3)
    matrix_input = []
    print("Enter the entries in a single line (separated by space): ")

    for i in range(row):  # A for loop for row entries
        ints =input()

        entries = []

        for a in ints:
          entries.append(int(a))
        matrix_input.append(entries)

    for ele in matrix_input:
      for d in ele:
        print(d,end='')
      print('')

matrix()
```

Input:

```
Enter the entries in a single line (separated by space): 
130
304
603
```

Output:

```
130
304
603
```

Comment: I like this but there are two problems. 
1. I'm not setting a column size anywhere
2. Output on my end has a new line for each entry

Comment: Yes, Column size problem can be eliminated easily using list comprehension, but new line is a problem,

Comment: How would I solve the new line problem? The example in your output is perfect but mine has a new line between each 3 digit number.

Comment: I update my answer, both of your problems has eliminated.

Comment: It still doesn't account for column length. I can enter 5 digits in the column and it works now.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking to do.

Comment: I can't understand what is problem, describe more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to convert an entire string (the input with spaces between each int) to an integer.

Instead you need to split out the input. See below:

```
def matrix():
    row = int(3)
    column = int(3)
    matrix_input = []
    print("Enter the entries in a single line (separated by space): ")
    
    input_str = input()
    
    entries = []
    entries.extend([int(x) for x in input_str.split(' ')])
    
    for item in entries:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick.

```py
def matrix():
    row = int(3)
    column = int(3)
    matrix_input = []
    print("Enter the entries in a single line (separated by space): ")
    for i in range(row):  # A for loop for row entries
        # ints = input().split()
        while True:
            ints = input().split()
            if len(ints) == 3:
                break
            print("Invalid Input Received")
            print("Enter the entries in a single line (separated by space): ")
        entries = []
        for a in ints:
            entries.append(int(a))
        matrix_input.append(entries)
    print("Output")
    for ele in matrix_input:
        for d in ele:
            print(d, end=' ')
        print('')
```